# Column data substring matching with Jackcess

Tags: java, jackcess

In my Access db table, I have a `cmt_data` column which contains a string. For example:

`Check in the packet TM(12,9) MRSS0319 'Monitoring List Report'.`

I also have a `List<String>` with items such as `MRSS0319`, `TRPP3006`, etc. What I'm looking to do is perform a substring match between my `List<String>` and the table column, but I can't quite figure out how as the examples provided with Jackcess is rather simple. An example I found [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/jackcess/discussion/456474/thread/41f878d3/) shows:

```
Column col = table.getColumn("town");
cursor.beforeFirst();
while(cursor.moveToNextRow()) {
  if(cursor.currentRowMatches(columnPattern, valuePattern)) {
    // handle matching row here
  }
}
```

Where the method `cursor.currentRowMatches(columnPattern, valuePattern)` looks like it could be useful. However according to the documentation it seems that the method only performs string equality matching, so now I'm sort of at a dead end.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: [Jackcess API Docs](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/apidocs/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly you could create a little method to check the `cmt_data` value for a match:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String dbPath = "C:/Users/Public/JackcessTest.accdb";
    try (Database db = DatabaseBuilder.open(new File(dbPath))) {
        Table table = db.getTable("cmt_table");
        Cursor cursor = table.getDefaultCursor();
        cursor.beforeFirst();
        while (cursor.moveToNextRow()) {
            Row row = cursor.getCurrentRow();
            if (stringContainsSpecialValue(row.getString("cmt_data"))) {
                // handle matching row here
                System.out.println(row);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
}

private static boolean stringContainsSpecialValue(String str) {
    boolean rtn = false;
    List<String> specialValues = Arrays.asList("MRSS0319", "TRPP3006");
    for (String val : specialValues) {
        if (str.contains(val)) {
            rtn = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return rtn;
}
```

You could probably also create a custom [ColumnMatcher](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/healthmarketscience/jackcess/util/ColumnMatcher.html) for your cursor, but that might be overkill.

Comment: great answer, but I'm looking to write back changes into Access if a substring was found. In that case, do I have to do `cursor.updateCurrentRow(row)` ? I also note that example documentation is somewhat lacking for the Jackcess project which is letting the API down. Perhaps a documentation on SO could be opened under `jackcess` tag? Link [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jackcess)

Comment: Yes, you could use `cursor.updateCurrentRow`, or `table.updateRow`, or perhaps `cursor.setCurrentRowValue` to update just one column. As for documentation, I'd leave that for the Jackcess team to decide whether they want to maintain documentation here (instead of, or in addition to, the [cookbook](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/cookbook.html), the [Javadoc](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/apidocs/), and the unit tests in the source code).

Comment: I'm using `cursor.setCurrentRowValue(table.getColumn("cmt_data"), newString);` which seems to be working as per requirements. And sure, I've come across those it's just that it would've been better if there were more usage scenario samples, etc. Thanks a lot for your help nonetheless.